# Recaptcha error code 'connection-failed' on verification

Tags: php, recaptcha

When implementing recaptcha v2, I am given the error code `'connection-failed'` when trying to verify the recaptcha input.

I have followed this (https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-add-google-recaptcha-in-php-form/) tutorial as I had no luck with others that I found

```php
    require('src/autoload.php');

    $siteKey = 'my key';
    $secret = 'my key';

    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);

    $gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']; 
    $remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
    $recaptchaErrors = ''; 

    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);

    if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
        $error[] = "worked";
    } else {
        $recaptchaErrors = $resp->getErrorCodes(); 

        foreach($recaptchaErrors as $err)
        {
            $error[] = $err;
        }

    }
```

I have not had much luck finding any details on this error anywhere, and it is not documented on the official recaptcha page. I have edited the snippet above for testing purposes, but it would be sending an email.

Answer (score 7):

If `allow_url_fopen` is `off` in your `php.ini`, the connection will fail because `Recaptcha` uses `file_get_contents` to access the API by default. I would not enable this flag as it can pose a security risk.

My suggestion, if you have the php `curl` module installed, is to use `Recaptcha` with a `curl` connection:

```
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());
```

Comment: Not sure what changed, because our form was working before, but switching to the Curl backend fixed it up for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem while working locally in a node environment running node-php-awesome-server.
If you are trying to verify the reCaptcha response from localhost, with a localhost reCaptcha key pair, try from a live webserver (with relative key pair) instead.
For some reason sending the request from localhost returned me that error.
I suppose it has something to do with the development environment but did not investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem when i tried to include recaptcha in my website on localhost, i then tried this code on my live website(on the server) and it worked, hope this helps.

```
    $secret = 'your server side key from google';
    $post_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'secret' => $secret,
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
        'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $post_data));
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response =file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($response);
    if($result->success){
       echo "Success";
    }
    if (!$result->success) {
       echo "CAPTCHA verification failed.");
    }
```